# How to override specific classes of react-material components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to make it so my input can be smaller by utilizing less padding around the input. I'm also trying to recenter the label after that is complete.

It appears if root is being over written correctly but the other classes are not.

Can anyone explain to me why my class overrides are not being applied correctly to the input?

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    width: 275
  },
  outlined: {
    transform: "translate(7px, 10px) scale(1)"
  },
  input: {
    paddingLeft: 7,
    paddingTop: 9.25,
    paddingBottom: 9.25,
    paddingRight: 7
  }
}));
```

This is the rendered HTML I'm trying to use the class overrides to access...

```
<div class="MuiFormControl-root MuiTextField-root makeStyles-root-387">
    <label
        class="MuiFormLabel-root MuiInputLabel-root MuiInputLabel-formControl MuiInputLabel-animated MuiInputLabel-outlined"
        data-shrink="false"
        for="title-input">Title
    </label>
    <div class="MuiInputBase-root MuiOutlinedInput-root MuiInputBase-formControl">
        <fieldset
            aria-hidden="true"
            class="PrivateNotchedOutline-root-445 MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline"
            style="padding-left: 54px;">
            <legend class="PrivateNotchedOutline-legend-446" style="width: 0.01px;">
                <span>&#8203;</span>
            </legend>
        </fieldset>
        <input
            aria-invalid="false"
            class="MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input"
            id="title-input"
            type="text"
            value=""></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the actual TextField element.

```
<TextField
            classes={{
              ...classes,
              root: classes.root,
              outlined: classes.outlined,
              input: classes.input
            }}
            inputProps={{}}
            id="title-input"
            label="Title"
            variant="outlined"
          />
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-water-8jspp?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Including a CodeSandbox link is great, but please also include the relevant portions of the code in the question text.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, added the relevant code, let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: Please show the code that uses `useStyles` and how you leverage the resulting classes.